# Create new df column with inputs from column 1, based on condition from column 2

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF with 50ish columns and duplicate ID's. The section I'm interested in kind of looks like this

```
   ID      Value         year
0   3       200          1995   
1   3       100          2001
2   4       300          1995
3   4       250          2000
```

All first entries of each ID = 1995, however the second entries correspond to a ValuedFrom column (the second entry is the retirement age of each object, and so its last value in most cases). Id like to merge all three of these columns so that I end up with two, like so

```
     ID  Value1995   ValueRetired
0   3       200           100   
1   4       300           250
```

Any ideas on how I might do this?

Comment: There is always first value row with  `1995` per groups ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution:

```
print (df)
   ID  year  Value
1   3  2003     95
2   3  1995    200
2   3  2001    100
3   4  1995    300
4   4  2000    250
5   4  2004    150
6   5  2000    201
7   5  1995    202 <- remove this row with 1995, because last value of group 5, if seelct next row it is in another group
8   6  2000    203
9   6  2000    204
```

First select indices of `1995` and all next rows:

```
idx = df.index[(df['year'] == 1995) & (df.groupby('ID').cumcount(ascending=False) != 0)]
idx2 = df.index.intersection(idx + 1).union(idx)
df = df.loc[idx2]
print (df)
   ID  year  Value  ValuedFrom
2   3  1995    200        1995
2   3  2001    100        2001
3   4  1995    300        1995
4   4  2000    250        2000
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('ID').cumcount(ascending=False))
1    2
2    1
2    0
3    2
4    1
5    0
6    1
7    0
8    1
9    0
dtype: int64
```

Then change values of column `year` for reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['year'] = np.where(df['year'] == 1995, 'Value1995', 'ValueRetired')

df = df.set_index(['ID', 'year'])['Value'].unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   ID  Value1995  ValueRetired
0   3        200           100
1   4        300           250
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a series mapping `year` to labels, then use [`pd.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['YearType'] = np.where(df['year'] == 1995, 'Value1995', 'ValueRetired')

res = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='YearType', values='Value')

print(res)

YearType  Value1995  ValueRetired
ID                               
3               200           100
4               300           250
5               150            95
```